# Get YouTube Unsubscribed Channel Trailer

Tags: jquery, json, youtube-api, youtube-channels

YouTube has a feature in which you can have a video on your channel for unsubscribed users to view when they visit your channel.  I'm trying to find a way to display this video on a web page using JSON (ASP.NET MVC4) but I'm not that familiar with all the tags and such.  I looked up some info on Google, here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels and found this: `brandingSettings.channel.unsubscribedTrailer` but I am not too sure how to access it.

Here's my code:
    $(document).ready(function () {

```
    var playListURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/XXXXXXXXXXXX?v=2&alt=json&max-results=50&callback=?';
    var videoURL = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
    $.getJSON(playListURL, function (data) {
        var list_data = "";
        var column_count = -1;
        var end_li = "</li>";
        var begin_div = "<div class='inner-item'>";
        var end_div = "</div>";
        var html_data = "";
        var tags = new Array();

        $.each(data.feed.entry, function (i, item) {
            column_count = column_count + 1;
            var feedTitle = item.title.$t;
            var feedURL = item.link[1].href;
            var videoDate = new Date(item.published.$t).toLocaleDateString()
            var fragments = feedURL.split("/");
            var videoID = fragments[fragments.length - 2];
            var description = item.media$group.media$description.$t;
            var url = videoURL + videoID;
            var thumb = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoID + "/default.jpg";

            //Do some stuff with the vid.
            });
        });
```

Do I need to access a different URL for this or can I find the info off the `item` property somewhere?

The above code was used to display all videos from a particular playlist and it works well (with all the code) but I just need to find the `unsubscribeTrailer` and display that, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You do have the wrong URL ... the documentation you reference that talks about the 'unsubscribedTrailer' field is for v3 of the API, but your code is doing a call to v2, where the field hasn't been exposed. Instead, you could try this URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,brandingSettings&id={DESIRED_CHANNEL_ID}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The important factor is to include 'brandingSettings' in your 'part' parameter, so that the fields you want are returned with the JSON response.

Comment: You are the final boss of a long research !